# Different behavior on unity editor and real device(android) while working on 2D joints?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working by unity 3D.I used some 2D joints(distant  joint 2D and hinge joint 2D) in my project.
In editor everything looks fine but in real android device the jointed object will
not show correctly and some objects will not visible at all. 
Why there's different result  on editor and real device(android) ?

Comment: We need to see what you are trying to do more clearly. Maybe you can provide some example project. Have you tried setting up simple scenes?

Comment: When diagnosing a broad problem right this, it's often good to reproduce it using the minimal system possible to research it further. Can you provide us with a description of a smallest possible system with 2d joins that shows this behavior? Also, in this process of elimination, you'll make sure that some of your code doesn't cause this problem, for example.

Comment: for example see this image . this chain is ok in editor but in real android device the chain will not show correctly. (image taken from android device) ....http://up.trolls.ir/uploads/143119158049651.png

Comment: have u find ur solution ?